# how to override border-collapse CSS settings within the HTML code?

Tags: html, css, border

Sorry if this is a basic question, but...
I have a CSS style for table with separate border collapse, but I would like to make only 2 cells within a table with collapsed borders.

something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcqeW.jpg)

how can I do this?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you cannot do that within a single table